# Dúvida sobre session()

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, banco-de-dados

Estou com uma dúvida sobre o uso de sessions. Estou montando um sistema de consulta dinâmica para pegar dados vindo do meu banco de dados quando clica em um link, cada link passa um id pela URL. Na página onde a mágica acontece, pego o ID pelo método _GET e passo ele via _SESSION para a página "processa" pegar ele e listar quais produtos pertencem ao ID "x". Só que, quando abro dois links ao mesmo tempo, quando utilizo o campo para pesquisar dinâmicamente, um acaba pesquisando o id do outro. Por exemplo:

Abri o link onde ele deve me mostrar itens com ID 1, minimizei essa janela e então abri outro link com o ID 2, então maximizo as 2 janelas (navegador) e pesquiso na janela que listou itens com ID 1 e acaba me mostrando itens com a ID 2 (sendo que tinha que continuar me mostrando com a ID 1).

Sei que é um pouco complicado para explicar e vocês entenderem mas, vou tentar melhorar adicionando as seguintes fotos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria que cada um, quando clicasse no link, abrisse a sua propria session, então, imagino que não teria mais esse problema.

Comment: Justamente, session não é pra isso. Constantemente vejo aqui no site o pessoal querendo armazenar tudo em session, e passar coisas entre páginas por session. Para passar coisas entre páginas normalmente se usa POST, GET, etc e não session. A session até pode servir de base temporária, mas precisa vincular a um ID específico cada grupo desejado.

Comment: Aí é que ta, tenho que passar o id para a outra pagina "processa" e pelo método POST teria que ter um submit certo? gostaria de fazer dinâmico.. algo como "submit onkeyup" no campo input.

Comment: Armazenar cada coisa de cada ID numa estrutura separada. Seja DB, seja ;txt, seja cookie ou session, precisa separar por assunto. Por exemplo, (aproveitando o session, só pra nao jogar tudo que vc fez fora), em vez de $_SESSION['lista'] usar $_SESSION['lista'][$id_da_unidade] ou algo do tipo (mesmo assim, acho session péssimo, pois se a pessoa perder a conexão, tem que começar do zero). Agora, se for coisa entre páginas, passe por POST ou GET mesmo.

Comment: não tenho problemas em desmontar, não tenho muito conhecimento em programação, sei mais o básico. Mas se há possibilidades de um GET, POST, sem um submit (dar um refresh na página no caso) poderia tentar usar esse método.

Comment: E o fato de ser dinâmico ou não independe disso. Tem como usar POST dinamicamente, ou mesmo por AJAX.

Comment: O importante é entender os prós e contras de cada método. Session é uma boa aliada desde que você entenda o que ela é e principalmente, o que ela não é. O nome já diz tudo, é para coisas relativas à sessão atual (algo como uma sequência ininterrupta de operações de um mesmo usuário, por um determinado periodo de tempo). Um dos efeitos dela é que várias abas no mesmo navegador (em uso normal) fazem parte da mesma session. Ou seja, você precisa criar um mecanismo próprio para gerenciar abas individualmente (session + id da aba, ou db + id da aba, esse id passado por get, post ou parte do url)

Comment: Entendi, teria algum exemplo desse método GET, POST que se encaixe mais ou menos na minha proposta para eu tentar?

Comment: Exemplo: em vez de /editarItens o caminho seria /editarItens?departamento=laboratorio e você usaria a variável $_SESSION['itens'][$departamento] para armazenar os itens, e não apenas $_SESSION['itens'], assim para cada $departamento (obtido com $GET) você tem uma lista separada - Ainda na session, mas separada por departamento. Mas não se prenda a essa idéia, cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Entendi.. estava pensando em talvez passar o ID do departamento em um campo input hidden com submit dinamico com ajax para pegar via GET na pagina processa, talvez eu consiga o que eu quero.. porque eu preciso especificar na query que eu quero itens de determinado departamento, se não ele me lista todos os itens